# HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request in PMC when fetching more than 300 articles

Tags: python, biopython

I'm trying to get articles (in text format) from PMC using this function I wrote :

```
from Bio import Entrez
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time

def get_pubmed_article(pmc_id):
       Entrez.email = "spidiagmir@gmail.com"
       start_time = time.time()
       handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pmc", id=pmc_id, rettype="xml")
       xml_data = handle.read()
       handle.close()
   
       soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data, 'xml')
       article_text = ''
       for section in soup.find_all('sec'):
           for paragraph in section.find_all('p'):
               article_text += paragraph.get_text(strip=True) + '\n\n'
   
       execution_time = time.time() - start_time
       if execution_time < 1 :
           time.sleep(1 - execution_time)
   
   return article_text
```

Apparently I can't request PMC more than 3 publications per second, otherwise I get the below error.
But even if I include a timer to my function the error persists. Is there a solution?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

[...]

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:643, in HTTPDefaultErrorHandler.http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
   642 def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 643     raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```